# Cannot run robotframework-hub

Tags: python, robotframework

I followed the installation instructions here [robotframework-hub](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-hub) and after running this command `python -m rfhub`
I get the following error `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named libdocpkg; 'rfhub' is a package and cannot be directly executed`. I tried looking for 'libdocpkg' to install with pip but no luck. Has anyone installed this successfully?

Comment: It looks like you don't have robot framework installed, or that you have a file in your path named "robot.py", or a folder named "robot" that is _not_ robot framework? `libdocpkg` is a module inside robot framework.

Comment: Hmm, well I definitely have robotframework installed. I've been running tests successfully for months. And yes, the folder where I keep my scripts is called robot, is that the cause of this issue? That folder, by the way, is in my home directory ```/Users/{my-directory}/robot```

Comment: I just renamed my 'robot' folder and robotframework-hub worked. Thanks for providing insight. One question, since my robot directory is not in my PATH environment why would Python have issues running the hub?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had a folder called 'robot' where I placed all my robot scripts. Once I renamed that folder the hub worked like a charm. Thank you @Bryan Oakley for the clues provided.